# Magento: login required to view/order for one store/website

Tags: magento, authentication, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

Given a magento installation with multiple existing websites and stores, is it possible to create a new website/store that requires users to login before they can order a product? Optional visitors should not be able to see the products as well. I prefer a module or extension that works out of the box, and has a setting in the admin to require login. This may be a paid module.

I found the following extension from Mageparts.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/require-login.html

This is only useful if new user accounts have to be approved by us. I found another extension by mageparts:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/approve-customer-account.html

Questions:

- Does anyone use these extensions and do they work like they should?
- What are the alternatives for these extensions?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice Free extension [Login only catalog](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-only-catalog.html) by **Vinai Kopp**.You can easily modify it accoording to your requirement

Comment: I'll try it, but I can't open the Connect Manager locally at the moment, and don't want to mess with the production site.